Issues Enabling Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) with RAID SSDs on Windows Server
I am facing issues while enabling Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) on my Windows Server setup. Here are the details of my setup and the problem encountered:
Server Setup:
Server 1:

Domain Controller Server and Failover Cluster Manager.
Windows Server 2022 Standard

Server 2 (Cluster Node 1):

Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

Disks


DiskPart:



Server 3 (Cluster Node 2):

Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

Disks :



MegaRAID Controller:

RAID controller has been set up in JBOD mode.


Steps Taken:

Installed the required features on nodes from the cluster manager server.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName win-6pn5tsncl07.test_ad.local,win-slefc1bh2f8.test_ad.local {
    Install-WindowsFeature FS-FileServer,Failover-Clustering,Hyper-V -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
}


Manually restarted both cluster nodes.

Created the cluster:
New-Cluster -Name Test-Cluster -Node win-6pn5tsncl07.test_ad.local,win-slefc1bh2f8.test_ad.local -StaticAddress 192.168.10.10 -NoStorage


Ran cluster validation


Cluster Validation Report:

Failed to list all disks for Storage Spaces Direct: 

Error Summary:

Node 1 

No eligible disks were found on which to perform cluster validation tests.
Eligible disks must comply with the following:

Default supported bus types are "SAS", "SATA" and "NVMe"
Disks with a SAS or NVMe bus types must support page 83
Disks with a SATA bus types must support page 80
A disk with no partition table (RAW) or a partition table with a GPT or an MBR format is supported
Disks with a GPT partition table must not contain any system or basic data partitions
Disks with an MBR partition table may only contain unused, logical disk manager (LDM), or Microsoft Storage Spaces partitions

Disk won't be eligible either if any of the following is true:

Disk is a boot volume
Disk is a system volume
Disk is used for paging files
Disk is a hibernate disk
Disk is used for memory dump files
Disk is removable
The port driver used by the disk does not support clustering
Disk type is dynamic
Disk is in use by another application
Disk is a redundant multipath I/O (MPIO) disk
Disk is a snapshot disk
Disk belongs to a non primordial storage pool
Disk is failing IO. Control code failures
Disk is unreadable

Disk0: Disk is a boot volume. Disk is a system volume. Disk is used for paging files. Disk bus type does not support clustering. Disk partition style is GPT. Disk has a System Partition. Cannot cluster a disk with a System Partition. Disk has a Microsoft Reserved Partition. Disk has a Basic Data Partition. Cannot cluster a disk with a Basic Data Partition.. Disk has a Microsoft Recovery Partition. Disk type DYNAMIC. Disk does not have non-volatile
Disk1: Disk bus type does not support clustering. No disk partition style defined. Disk is RAW. Disk type is BASIC. Disk does not have non-volatile cache.
Disk2: Disk bus type does not support clustering. No disk partition style defined. Disk is RAW. Disk type is BASIC. Disk does not have non-volatile cache.

Node 2 


Those validation failure reasons seem ... really descriptive.
